# Serialization in C# and de-serialization in Java

Tags: c#, java, serialization, deserialization

Is it possible to serialize the class/object in C# and deserialize the same in java. I want to serialize the class and not any XML/JSON data. Please clarify.

Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible, what have you tried?

Comment: @Aada, Not sure if you're able to say so, but why don't you want to use `XML` or `JSON`.  I just want to make sure that this isn't going to end up being a case of the [XY-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: @SteveP. nice link to XY, never seen that.

Comment: @Aada, serialization is a broad term. Do you care what the output format is? I've concentrated on binary in my answer below, however if you prefer text based JSON or XML are really the best alternatives.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Yeah, it's interesting. I briefly read the question and of course made a post about JSON/XML, which was immediately downvoted.  When I saw that the OP explicitly stated that they shouldn't be used, that striked me as potentially odd, so I wanted to ask for clarification.

Comment: HI steve. The reason behind is I don't want the file to be as in xml format since to read/parse the xml file takes much longer in my case. And ya, that was the only reason i downvoted.

Comment: @Aada So are you looking for binary or text serialization? or do you have preference?

Comment: @WilliamMorrison: Binary willam.

Comment: Great! Hopefully my answer helps you then. Good luck!

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Ya i was looking at your answer itself. I have a big condition, i want my de-serlization mechanism to be done in a best efficient way which means faster. Can you please suggest which approach,as suggested by you would be better?

Comment: I would use the first one. I've updated my answer for you @Aada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see 3 options here. I suggest option 1, Protobufs.

**Look into Google's ProtoBufs**

Or some equivalent.  Here's the [java version.](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)  Here's a [C# port.](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/)

Protobufs meant for this sort of language interop.  Its binary, small, fast, and language agnostic.

Also it has backwards compatibility, so if you change the serialized objects in the future, you can still read them.  This feature is transparent to you too, long as you write code understanding newer variables could be missing when unserialized old objects. This is a huge advantage!

**Implement one language's default serialization in the other**

You can try implementing the java serialization logic in C#, or the C# serialization routines in Java.  I don't suggest this as it will be more difficult, more verbose, almost certainly slower as you're writing new code, and will net you the same result.

**Write your serialization routines by hand**

This will certainly be fast, but tedious, more error prone, harder to maintain, less flexible...

[Here's some benchmarks](http://code.google.com/p/thrift-protobuf-compare/wiki/Benchmarking) for libraries like ProtoBufs. This should aide you in selecting the best one for your use case.

Comment: Hi Willam, i am trying to understand protocol-buffer, but didn't found any good tutorials, i tried something like this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063793/how-to-de-serialize-the-file-in-java-by-using-protocol-buffer. Please suggest.

Comment: Will do. Please accept and close this question as you've started a new one?

Answer (score 1):

We did this a while ago, it worked after lot of tinkering, it really depends on byte encoding, i think JAva uses one and C# uses another (little endian vs. big endian) so you will need to implement a deserializer which takes this affects into account. hope this helps

Comment: My company had to solve this same problem, luckily we used a custom protocol rather than the built in serialization of either language. Got a feeling it would have been rough otherwise. +1 for your struggles.

Comment: Thanks, we are all battle scared :) this protobuff stuff looks promising but I assume it will have its own demons.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, though I've been lucky enough not to encounter any yet.

Comment: HI Mehul, i am completely don't have any idea regarding this.. could you please help in making me understand how it would be possible to create your own deserializer.?

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, your options are going to be external serialization libraries (Google Protobuff, [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/), etc), or simply using something built-in that's slower/less efficient bandwidth-wise (JSON, XML, etc). You could also write your own, but believe me, it's a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Not using native serialization.  The built-in defaults are tied to the binary representation of the data types, which are different for the different VMs.  The purpose of XML, JSON, and similar technologies is precisely to provide a format that's generic and can be moved between differing systems.  For what it's worth, the overhead in serializing to JSON is usually small, and there's a lot of benefit to being able to read the serialized objects manually, so I'd recommend JSON unless you have a very specific reason why you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Consider OMG's standard CORBA IIOP.

While you many not need the full-on "remote object" support of CORBA, IIOP is the underlying binary protocol for "moving language-neutral objects" (such as an object value parameter) across the wire.

- For Java: Java EE EJB's are based on IIOP, there is RMI-IIOP; various support libraries.  The [IDL-to-Java compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/idlj.html) is delivered with the JDK.
- For C# IIOP & integration with Java EE, see [IIOP.NET](http://iiop-net.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/), which is used by MongoDB.
If it is OK for your C#/Java programs to communicate with a mongodb database, you could store your objects there and read it with the appropriate driver.

Regarding BSON itself, see [BSON and Data Interchange](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/9333386434/bson-and-data-interchange) at the mongoDB blog.